# How to Send Video from a Raspberry Pi (HDMI) to 20 pin LVDS

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, lvds

Through *shenanigans*, I have come to possess 4 small LCD screens. I've found the pin-out for video data on page 12 of [this datasheet](http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/489821/18147070/1388691450350/NL8060BC21-02.pdf?token=gqIgV5ULWv0ZKvp43BFTUecCc0U%3D). I think it's LVDS. I'd like to know what I need to learn to be able to connect this screen to my Raspberry Pi. From what I've read about people attempting similar things, I believe I need to make or find a controller board(?) I know I'm probably way out of my depth, since most of my electronics experience is Arduino's and breadboards. Still, I'm at the point where I'm trying to make mistakes and learn.

If this is far beyond a novice, I'd also appreciate any suggestions on other projects I could use these screens for, and hopefully learn something in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raspberry Pi uses [DSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Serial_Interface) protocol for LCD displays, which your LCDs don't seem to support.

While making a controller board is possible, it's definitely not an easy project. Not only you will have to interface your LCDs properly, but you'll also have to decode the DSI commands Raspberry Pi sends. HDMI is even more complex to decode and process.

If your goal is to play with the LCDs, you could try to follow the datasheet and see if you can do something simple such as filling all pixels with a given color and see how that goes. If your goal is to get a display for your Pi, just buy one.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend building a converter from scratch. Look for "HDMI LVDS" on Aliexpress. You will find lots of "graphics cards" that do HDMI to LVDS conversion. 20-30 USD range.